# Amazon Cloud Reader – Download or Print

Tags: ubuntu, cloud

I purchased a book in Amazon and it added it to the kindle cloud. The cloud reader application was installed in Chrome running on Ubuntu. I downloaded the book for offline reading. My questions are

1. Where is the book saved on disk?
2. Is it possible to take a print out of the book since I prefer reading it old style?

Comment: You could essentially locate the location of the book that has been downloaded but chances are that is contains DRM http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to print the book, since it is DRM.
It is not supported.
However, you can go manually every page through, take screenshots and combine a book, but it is burdensome. 
Nevertheless, you can program this by mirrowing the screen to other display where you ask the system to browse pages in steady intervals and take screenshots. 
There is a very nice Linux terminal program called **Xdotool** for this which you bind then to a small script for mouse clicking. 
If Amazon is going to detect this, then put some random timing to hide the machine.
You can automate this for many books (I think maximum 3 devices at the some time) by using TTYs.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon doesn't allow us to print total book content from Kindle Cloud Reader. It only allows us to print one page.

[Is It Possible to Print from Kindle Cloud Reader in 2023](https://youtu.be/oIn4luoDugU)

Comment: Whst am i missing? Sounds reasonable to me. If you want a hard copy then pay for one.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1167549)

Answer (score 0):

The books you buy from Amazon Kindle are protected with DRM, by the terms and conditions of Amazon you are not allowed to make copies of any form of them. This of course includes physical copies you would print.

Nevertheless the question of removing DRM from software or downloaded files is not allowed here as it is not completely clear if it is legally ok to remove it for just personal use or if that is already illegal as well.

In Germany where I live it is ok to want to read it on ebook readers made by other companies, and as mine doesn't support Amazon's AZW3 format, I need to remove the DRM in order to convert it to EPUB. I do so using a plugin for the popular ebook management software [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/). If you do a little research, you will find the DRM removal plugin, but I cannot link to it here as it could be illegal in some countries.